# Python - Strings, Lists (Password checker)

Tags: python, string, list, passwords

I am trying to figure out what my code is doing wrong that isn't working correctly. Even if I use a lowercase, uppercase, or number in my code, it still prints out statements saying I don't. Please help!

```
# function to check if the password is a valid one 
def validatePassword(userPassword):

    # if the user has a lowercase character, then the password
    # meets validation requirements
    lowercase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    if lowercase in userPassword:
        hasLowercase = True
    else:
        hasLowercase = False
        print("A lowercase letter is required. ")

    # if the user has an uppercase character, then the password
    # meets validation requirements
    uppercase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    if uppercase in userPassword:
        hasUppercase = True
    else:
        hasUppercase = False
        print("An uppercase letter is required. ")

    # if the user has a digit, then the password
    # meets validation requirements
    digits = "1234567890"
    if digits in userPassword:
        hasDigits = True
    else:
        hasDigits = False
        print("A digit is required. ")

    # if user enters a space, then the password
    # does NOT meet validation requirements
    whitespace = " "
    if whitespace in userPassword:
        hasWhitespace = True
        print("Password must not contain a space.")
    else:
        hasWhitespace = False

    # the user has successfully met all validation requirements
    if ((hasLowercase == True) and (hasUppercase == True) and (hasDigits == True) and (hasWhitespace == False)):
        return True

# the user is inputting passwords     
def main():
    print("Please input passwords one-by-one for validation. ")
    print("Enter END after you've entered your last password. ")
    passwordList = [""]
    while ("END" not in passwordList):
        passwordList.append(str(input("")))
    del passwordList[-1]
    for x in range(1,(len(passwordList))):
        userPassword = passwordList[x]

        # user has come up with a good password
        if (validatePassword(userPassword) == True):
            print("Password " + userPassword + " is good ")

        # user has come up with a bad password
        else:
            print("Password " + userPassword + " is bad ")

main ()
```

Comment: Please check how `in` works. When you say `if "asd" in word:` python checks if `asd` as whole is in `word`. Not `a` or `s` or `d` individually.

Comment: should i use commas in between each individual letter or make it a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `if '123' in s` you check that the entire `123` string is a substring. Not each individual character.

Change this to:

```
if any((c in s) for c in '123')
```

And your code will work.
Note that I would recommend that you look at the string method `upper` and `lower`, and look at the module `re` (regular expressions). That will help you write better code for this case.

EDIT:

In your specific case, use:

```
lowercase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    if any((c in userPassword) for c in lowercase):
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. so, in my case would it be:

    if ((lowercase in userPassword) for lowercase in 'abc')

Comment: i'm confused by the variables you have, the c and the s as well as the "any"

Comment: I added the exact line you can paste in your code. Use the same thing for all your if statements. Any is simply a built in function.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
import getpass
import string

# function to check if the password is a valid one 
def validatePassword(userPassword):

    # if the user has a lowercase character, then the password
    # meets validation requirements
    lowercase = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    hasLowercase = True
    if not any([True if i in lowercase else False for i in userPassword]):
        print("A lowercase letter is required. ")
        hasLowercase = False


    ## if the user has an uppercase character, then the password
    ## meets validation requirements
    uppercase = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
    hasUppercase = True
    if not any([True if i in uppercase else False for i in userPassword]):
        print("An uppercase letter is required. ")
        hasUppercase = False

    ## if the user has a digit, then the password
    ## meets validation requirements
    digits = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
    hasDigits = True
    if not any([True if i in digits else False for i in userPassword]):
        print("A digit is required. ")
        hasDigits = False

    ## if user enters a space, then the password
    ## does NOT meet validation requirements
    whitespace = " "
    if whitespace in userPassword:
        hasWhitespace = True
        print("Password must not contain a space.")
    else:
        hasWhitespace = False

    ## the user has successfully met all validation requirements
    if ((hasLowercase == True) and (hasUppercase == True) and (hasDigits == True) and (hasWhitespace == False)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("\nPlease input passwords one-by-one for validation\n(Type END after you've entered your last password): ")
    passwordList = []

    while True:
        current_password = getpass.getpass()   # so user password doesn't display on screen, for security reasons. Use next line if you don't want this function.
        #current_password = raw_input()

        if "END" in current_password:
            break

        if current_password:
            passwordList.append(str(current_password))

    for i, userPassword in enumerate(passwordList):
        if validatePassword(userPassword):
            result = "\nPassword " + str(i) + " is good "   # change i to userPassword if you want to print password to screen, NOT RECOMMENDED
        else:
            result = "\nPassword " + str(i) + " is bad "

        print(result)
```